# Grab downloaded data when error "Connection was lost" occurs in swift + alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm developing an iOS app in Xcode 6 with swift and using alamofire.

In the app user can download a large size file.The question is if I get "connection was lost" error, how I can grab downloaded data to resume later and not to start from the beginning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/pull/595,
Alamofire implemented follows features:

> 1.For any failed download request, the resume data is automatically extracted out of the error object if it is available.
>
> 2.Added a resumeData computed property on the Request to allow you to access that data outside the response serialization methods. For example, you can now access the resumeData in any of the chained Request methods if you so choose.